# How would I represent a compound key in Scala?

Tags: scala

If I have

```
val key1 = "mykey"
val key2 = 427
```

Is it possible to hash by both? I could do something like

```
val compoundKey = key1 + "#" + key2
myhash.put(compoundKey, value)
```

However that seems a bit clunky

Comment: Are you going to accept an answer or are you looking for another one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I always prefer the new data type over Tuple for three reasons:

```
case class CompoundKey(key1: String, key2: String)
```

1. You have a name, especially in compiler warnings and an "`expected CompoundKey`" is clearer than a "`expected Tuple2[String,String]`". Or it just helps you with a type annotation to make your own code more readable, especially in nested structures like Maps

   `val k: CompoundKey = expensiveComputationOrNonObviousMethodCallsInARow(...)`
   `val keyMap: Map[CompoundKey,Key]` instead of `Map[(String,String),Key]`
2. Access to the subkeys in CompoundKey can be done by name:

   `val ckey = CompoundKey("foo","bar")`
   `ckey.key1` instead of `ckey._1`
3. It lets you change your representation of the nested type, here `String`, later on. That means if you change `String` to whatever that you doesn´t have to change `Tuple2[String,String]` all over your code. Only `CompoundKey` has to be adapted.

(I even would use a wrapper `case class Key(str: String)` for the key class)

Comment: Note that `Tuple2` is specialized over `Int`, `Long` and `Double`.

Answer (score 13):

Use a `Tuple`:

```
val compoundKey = (key1, key2)
```

Comment: Or if the key values have some sort of meaning when put together, then create a new data type to represent the grouping.